# Codeigniter : get variable from another controller

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

i have the following controller to display a login form (the very first page)

```
public function index()
{
    $data['form_type']='dologin';
    $data['username_label']='Username';
    $data['password_label']='Password';
    $data['username_name']='usernamenya';//name of the textbox username
    $data['password_name']='passwordnya';//name of the textbox password
    $data['username_value']='';
    $data['password_value']='';
    $data['fieldset_text']='Silahkan Login';        
    $data['fieldset_close_text'] = '</div></div>';
    $data['form_close_text']='</div></div>';
    $data['clear_name']='Hapus';
    $data['submit_name']='Login';

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('content_login',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');        
}
```

after the button is clicked, it will redirect to `dologin` controller, i have created `index` function on `dologin` controller

```
class dologin extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('','','');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
}   
      }
```

in the `form_validation_rules` which require the name of control, i want to get it from another controller, so, if we change the name in `index` controller, `dologin` controller won't break and still continue the process

how do i do that ?
or is there any alternative way to make my idea ?

Comment: I don't understand. How will you know what validation rule needs to be applied if the fields are sent dynamically ?

Comment: @AdrienXL that's why, i want to call the `usernamenya` and `passwordnya` from `index` controller,  so, if some other time we change the `usernamenya` into `stack_usernamenya` , that won't be a problem . . .

Comment: You can add a hidden input in your form which contains `serialize($data)` and when you post your form to `dologin` controller then youcan unserialize it. but a better way is to create a `config/form.php` that contains your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've completely understood your problem, but here is how I would do that kind of stuff :

---

Let's say we have a basic html form for login in which we ask for an email and a password :

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url("myController/login"); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="login_mail" required>
    <input type="password" name="login_pass" required>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>                
</form>
```

As you can see, submitting the form will call the function `login()` in the controller `myController` as defined in the `action` attribute.

Let's see that `login()` function :

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //Here we set the validation rules for our two fields. We must use the same names as defined in out html for the `name` attribute.
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login_mail', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login_pass', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) //Success
        {
            //Get the submited values
            $email = $this->input->post("login_mail");
            $password = $this->input->post("login_pass");

            //Your stuff here

            $this->load->view('formsuccess');            
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
    }  
}
```